# Powershell on MacOS is not finding installed modules

Tags: powershell

I have installed Powershell for MacOS. Then I installed some modules: They were installed in `~/.local/share/powershell/Modules`.
When I want to use them, Powershell cannot find them: Running `Connect-AzureAD`, I get the error

> Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: `"$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules"` _should_ be listed in `$env:PSModulePath` (PowerShell itself ensures its presence) - is it not? Note that if you use a _preview_ version of PowerShell 7.4 in combination with installing modules via `Install-PSResource` rather than `Install-Module`, a _different_ directory is installed to; this will should be fixed wen v7.4 is officially released - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet/issues/1454

Comment: @U. Windl i use powershell version 7.3.9 and allways install with Install-Module .what you mean by "$HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules" should be listed in $env:PSModulePath ? how can check that (i am relatively new on powershell :) ) ?

Comment: @U. Windl : ok i just did run the $env:PSModulePath in powershell and the path listed there is : /Users/santiago/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules . is that wrong ? could it help to move the "user" modules just to the default modules folder ?

Comment: This looks correct. Is this the only error message you're getting, or is there another one about a module not being able to be loaded? `Get-Module -List | % Path` lists the paths of all modules that PowerShell can discover based on `$env:PSModulePath` - unless [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) has explicitly been disabled.

Comment: it's quite strange. it does discover all the modules i installed, but i still get the same error. how can i check if module auto-loading is disabled (i just installed powershell from the package and then installed 3 modules). i did not disable anything, at least intentionally.

Comment: here is what i get when running Get-Module -List | % Path

PS /Users/santiago> Get-Module -List | % Path
/Users/santiago/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD/2.0.2.182/AzureAD.psd1

etc etc

but still when i try Connect-AzureAD i receive :

PS /Users/santiago> Connect-AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Auto-loading is (unconditionally) enabled if the value of `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` is either `$null` or `'All'`. Try to import the module explicitly, with `-Verbose`: `Import-Module AzureAd -Verbose`

Comment: $PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference does not output anything. the import with -verbose output = Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
PS /Users/santiago>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**:

- **If you're using an *ARM*-based Mac (M1 chip and above)**, the **[`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread) module is *incompatible*** with it and cannot be used, for the reasons explained in the next section, which generally describes how PowerShell handles modules that are incompatible with the system at hand.
- However, the **[`AzureAD` module is *deprecated*](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270)**, and its successor, **[`Microsoft.Graph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation) *does* appear to run on ARM-based Macs**, so switching to this module may implicitly solve your problem.

---

**Troubleshooting modules that are incompatible with the system at hand:**

Unfortunately, neither `Install-Module` nor its successor, [`Install-PSResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.psresourceget/install-psresource?view=powershellget-3.x) - as of v1.0.0 - prevent installation of *incompatible* modules.

PowerShell's module discovery and module [auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading)
for the most part *ignore* incompatible modules: attempts to call their commands are treated like *nonexistent* commands, tab-completion doesn't work, and `Get-Module -List` omits such modules *except* if you also specify `-All` (e.g. `Get-Module -List -All Azure*`)

The only way to discover the specific compatibility problem is with an `Import-Module` call with the literal module name (wildcards don't work).

In the case at hand, e.g. on a Mac with M1 chip, `Import-Module AzureAD` results in the following error:

```
Import-Module: The current processor architecture is: MSIL. The module '/Users/jdoe/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureAD/2.0.2.182/AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.
```

The root cause is that the `AzureAD` module's [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) has a `ProcessorArchitecture = 'Amd64'` entry.

I'm unclear on whether other entries can cause incompatibility too.
(The `DotNetFrameworkVersion`, `CLRVersion` and `CompatiblePSEditions` do *not*, even when their values do not apply to PowerShell (Core) / .NET (Core)).

*De-facto failure to load .NET assemblies* required by a given module results in *similar* symptoms to incompatible module based on its `ProcessorArchitecture` value: Commands are treated as nonexistent, but `Get-Module` *does* tab-complete and list such a module with `-List` alone.